# What are the main attributes of modern file systems?

Tags: filesystems

I'm working my way down the stack but haven't yet learned about filesystems. When comparing filesystems, what are the main attributes I can expect to encounter in my research?

The Wikipedia [topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) is... a bit daunting. If I want to focus on the "palpable" attributes of a modern filesystem (journaling, blocks, chunks etc.), what are the main attributes on which to focus?

Comment: The only interesting parts (in finding out the main attributes of file systems) of that web page are the titles of the *Features* and * Allocation and layout policies* tables, and the fact that there is a *Metadata* section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important attribute is likely to be

- Reliability

because you want the data to be safely written and retrieved at anytime.
Usually it takes years to have a FS tried and tested.
Integrity leads to dependencies. For instance, in special occasions, like power cut or system crash,

- Data integrity

is a crucial factor. *Journaling* is commonly an attribute that maximizes data integrity.

- Speed

is also important. *Journaling* is likely to slow down write operations.
Speed depends also upon the implementation of the FS, using of memory, caches...

- Systems versatility

Is the FS readable from another operating system? For instance, it works on Linux, but can you mount and read it from Mac OS?

Other attributes may or may not an important factor, depending on your needs

- Encryption: does the FS handle data encryption, requiring a key to mount it?
- Read-only: an attribute to allow a write-protected mount
- *relatime* like attribute, allow to write the *access* time only during write operations (to minimize the TOC writings)

For instance, [some explanations of the ext4](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1096467) file system mount options.

*Edit* - about the Access Control List (per-user / group access to the data)

The ACL is not really an *attribute* of the FS.
It can be integrated within the file system, but, depending on the FS, mounting from a platform to a different platform may completely override the user access control. The global access being controlled by lower level attributes. as the ones detailed above for instance.

Comment: You've missed *security*: the ability to define who can perform different types of access to different objects in the file system.

Comment: @Richard See my edit

Comment: @ring0: I don't follow your logic. Security can be bypassed on most OSs by the "root" user, this doesn't mean the file system's security is irrelevant (especially where many users make use of the file system).

Comment: @Richard, File security is just metadata that the OS interprets and enforces. **The File System does not enforce security**. Root can only override security because of how it interacts with the kernel; the file system on disk couldn't care less about root.

Comment: @ChrisS: That's also true for data integrity mechanisms and read-only (at least). The OS software just sees a sequence of raw blocks: everything else is down to the file system implementation in software from the OS. All file system features are down to what the software implementation provides.

Comment: A comment about "Journaling is commonly an attribute that maximizes data integrity." Journaling maximizes file-system (meta-data) integrity but doesn't prevent against silent data corruption. If you expect data integrity, look to file systems that checksum every block.